# Webpack not including all dependencies on deploying serveless application

Tags: webpack, serverless, pg

Am getting an error when I am deploying serverless lambda function on AWS

```
"errorMessage": "Please install pg package manually"
```

I observe that serverless is not including all dependencies from pakage.json. pg and pg-hoster package is missing.

```
Serverless: Packing external modules: source-map-support@^0.5.19, dotenv@^10.0.0, ajv@^8.6.1, 
ajv-errors@^3.0.0, @middy/core@^1.5.2, @middy/http-json-body-parser@^1.5.2, sequelize@6.6.5, 
bcryptjs@^2.4.3, jsonwebtoken@^8.5.1
```

my webpack.config file is

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
/*
This line is only required if you are specifying `TS_NODE_PROJECT` for whatever reason.
*/
// delete process.env.TS_NODE_PROJECT;

module.exports = {
context: __dirname,
mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
entry: slsw.lib.entries,
devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts', 'js'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
 plugins: [
    new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
      configFile: './tsconfig.paths.json',
     }),
   ],
 },
 output: {
   libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
   path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
   filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
  concatenateModules: false,
 },
 target: 'node',
 externals: [nodeExternals()],
 module: {
   rules: [
     // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
    {
       test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
       loader: 'ts-loader',
       exclude: [
         [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
        ],
      ],
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
        experimentalWatchApi: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
plugins: [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    eslint: {
       files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}', // required - same as command `eslint ./src/**/*. 
      {ts,tsx,js,jsx} --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx`
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

and my serverless.ts file is look like

```
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';
import lambdas from './src/handlers/index';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'tapit-backend',
  frameworkVersion: '2',
  custom: {
    webpack: {
      webpackConfig: './webpack.config.js',
      includeModules: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-offline', 'serverless-prune-plugin'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
     },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      NODE_ENV: 'dev',
    },
    lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221',
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: lambdas,
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

could someone please help me where i am doing wrong. please

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution to your problem?  I'm running into the exact same issue.

Comment: I have figured out this issue, serverless pick only that packages which names are used somewhere in code (which is strange for me).
we can solve this issue by two methods
1) create a separate project with the name of "nodejs" install all require packages and upload it on lambda layers. 
2) just import pg-admin somewhere in code and log it (this is not preferable).

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! I have just burned 3 hours on a similar issue (graphql not being packed as an external module) and a simple `import 'graphql'` got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Full credit to this blog post](https://claudelalyre.wordpress.com/2019/08/07/webpack-and-error-please-install-pg-package-manually/)

You are developing a NodeJS + Webpack + Sequelize + pg + pg-hstore application. You compile everything and when you execute your webpack bundle, you have the following error

```
throw new Error(`Please install ${moduleName} package manually`);
Error: Please install pg package manually
```

You need to remove all nodes_modules librairies from your final bundle with NPM package “webpack-node-externals”.

To do this, just install it with

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-node-externals
```

In your webpack.config.js file, you need to import the plugin with

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
```

and in the “externals” section of this file, you need to declare

```
externals: [
    nodeExternals(),
],
```

Your final bundle will be smaller and you won’t have the Error: Please install pg package manually error message anymore.